# react-hook-form id not saved with useFieldArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Could someone figure out what's wrong with my code? I'm using react-hook-form's useFieldArray and want to generate a unique id for each field. I'm trying to do that with append but somehow the id field disappears. Even if I changed `keyname: 'newId'`, this isn't logged into the data.

I am also using Material UI.

My code:

```
...
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
          arrayName: {id: uuidv4(), name: "name goes here"}
        }
      });

    const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray(
        {
          control,
          name: "arrayName",
          // keyName: 'formId' // deafult and you can rename to others
        }
    );
...
                <TextField 
                    label="Test Type"
                    variant="outlined"
                    type="text"
                    name={`arrayName[${index}].name`}
                    defaultValue={`${field.name}`}
                    inputRef={register()}
                />
        <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            size="large"
            className={classes.button}
            startIcon={<AddCircleIcon />}
            onClick={() => append({ id: uuidv4(), type: "", score: 0 })}
        >
            Add Array Item
        </Button>
```

I have a submit button later that call this:

```
    const onSubmit = data => {
        handleArrayChange(originalArray.id, { ...originalArray, ...data })
        history.push(`/newURL`)
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example given in [react-hook-form docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFieldArray) `append` parameter object `key` should match with the field `name`

```
.../ some codes
<TextField name={`arrayName[${index}].id`} />
<TextField name={`arrayName[${index}].type`} />
<TextField name={`arrayName[${index}].score`} />

.../ some codes
 <Button onClick={() => append({ id: uuidv4(), type: "", score: 0 })} >
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that I have to have a textfield with the id? Is there a way to not surface that to the user? I imagine the textfield with a random long string could be confusing and off putting.

Comment: You can either loop through the submitted array and manually add id or use `input` type `hidden` or style the current textfield with `display:none`